# Turning part UTM, part degree coordinate into location on Google Maps?

Tags: coordinates, latitude-longitude, utm

I'm really new at this and not actually sure what kind of coordinate this is but I need to know where this coordinate leads to.
The cöordinates are part of a province wide "fox hunt" in gelderland, The Netherlands. I basically have to solve an obscure hint to find the exact location via coördinates. This hint involved a list of these weird coördinates. After a little research the only thing I found is that they might have to do something with UTM.

It reads

> 49510.24298m; 65.72307667 degrees

It should lead to somewhere in the Netherlands in the western part of the province: Gelderland. Can any of you guys help me out with this?

Comment: Where did this come from?

Comment: 65N is not in the Netherlands.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. 
Please take a look at the **[Tour]**.
And please also **[edit]** some extra info into the body of the question for clarification:
e.g. where did you get the coords; why are there so many (ridiculous) significant figures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the coordinates are both in meters, it could be `EPSG:28991 Amersfoort /RD Old` projection.

The point would then be between Apeldoorn and Zutphen.

Answer (score 1):

If you're *sure* the coordinates are distance (metres) and direction (degrees), then you have some form of *polar* coordinates -- a range and bearing from some origin. You would use simple cogo calculations to convert it to UTM -- and that's if you know the UTM coords of the origin. Such measures are often found on cadastral (boundary) maps, but the distances are not likely to be anywhere near as great as that in your example.

(However, I suspect AndreJ's assumption is the more likely interpretation.)